# How to setup neatx?

Tags: 11.04, neatx

How can I setup neatx server on ubuntu natty? I'm looking for a step by step guide from a fresh natty installation.

Answer (score 1):

> What is NeatX?

Neatx is an Open Source NX server, similar to the commercial NX server from NoMachine. If you're not familiar with NX, these links might help:

- [Wikipedia "NX technology"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology)
- [NoMachine's “Getting Started With NX”](http://www.nomachine.com/documents/getting-started.php)
- [Alternative: FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX)

[image]

<sub>random pixs of the web</sub>

> How to install NeatX?

Add the PPA, update and install:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install neatx-server`

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

edit: above installation seems to fail. From [google neatx page](http://code.google.com/p/neatx/):

Getting Neatx: At the moment, we're not doing releases as we're constantly fixing small things as people try out the codebase. In the meantime, the best way to get neatx is to [check it out from svn](http://code.google.com/p/neatx/source/checkout).

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:

`# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.`
`svn checkout http://neatx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ neatx-read-only`

Comment: This does not appear to work on Natty.  First command runs fine.  Second command (apt-get update) fails on the ppa.launchpad.net repository saying 404 Not Found.  Have you done this setup on natty?

Comment: That is what I have documented when I installed it in april. They must have deleted the PPA :) 1 moment \o

Comment: you are out of luck... they removed all downloads and you can only get it by checking it from svn

Comment: @Eric any reason why it has to be neatx? I'd go got Free NX if I was you (see the 3rd link)

Comment: "Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found"

Answer (score 0):

When you are behind a proxy :

```
user@host:~$ sudo bash
root@host:~$ export http_proxy=http://<proxyname>:<proxyport>/
root@host:~$ export https_proxy=http://<proxyname>:<proxyport>/
root@host:~$ add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
root@host:~$ sed -i 's/natty/lucid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freenx-team-ppa-natty.list
root@host:~$ apt-get update
root@host:~$ apt-get install neatx-server
root@host:~$ exit
```

sudo bash is to keep **export** commands effect for all the session.

Answer (score -1):

@ Eric

This should solve your problem in installing Neatx in Natty:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
sudo sed -i 's/natty/lucid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freenx-team-ppa-natty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neatx-server
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain what this does differently from the Rinzwind answer?